# Net-SNMP. How to cleanup memory after usage?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, snmp, net-snmp

I'm using net-snmp 5.8. on Windows 10 in C++ project (VS 2015 update 3) and want to find out how to cleanup memory the lib uses for it's purposes.

I called

```
snmp_shutdown(NETSNMP_APPLICATION_CONFIG_TYPE)
```

(initialized snmp before with the same param `init_snmp(NETSNMP_APPLICATION_CONFIG_TYPE)`) after closing session via `snmp_close()`, but there are some memory leaks left anyway. What is the proper way to cleanup memory here?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific and detailed as to why you think "there are some memory leaks left anyway" in order to get help.